# How to create a dynamic anchor link in nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a nuxt onepager that is feeded with content from the Wordpress Rest Api.

I'm already getting the Wordpress menu structure and every menu item is stored in {{ item.title }}. To scroll later to the requested div with it's id {{ item.title }} i want to complete the {{ item.title }} with a #.

My idea so far is:
`<nuxt-link to="'#'{item.title}'" exact class="nav-link">{{ item.title }}</nuxt-link>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind it as follows :

```
<nuxt-link :to="'#'+item.title" exact class="nav-link">{{ item.title }}</nuxt-link>
```